# Indented before caption in a Latex table or figure

Tags: tables, spacing, floats

I have a problem with the space before my caption.

When I run this sintaxis Latex throw a table and a figure.

My problem is the position of the caption. The first one (table) is ok; it is at the left, but in the second one the position of the caption is like 5 spaces at the right, like it would be if it were indented. I don't know what is wrong.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, spanish]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\begin{flushleft}

\end{flushleft}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=RaggedRight,labelfont=bf,textfont=bf,skip=10pt}
\captionsetup[figure]{justification=RaggedRight,labelfont=bf,textfont=bf,skip=10pt}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{20pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{0.75in}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\begin{document}


 \begin{table}[H]
 \caption{Asistencia a la educación de jóvenes de 14 a 17 según edades simples.}
 \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Asistencia}  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{2009} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}             
  {2010} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{2011}\\
\cline{2-2} \cline{3-3} \cline{4-4} \cline{5-5} \cline{6-6} \cline{7-7}
& Frecuencia & Porcentaje & Frecuencia & Porcentaje & Frecuencia & Porcentaje\\ 
  \hline
     No Asiste & 39.169 & 19,3\%    & 49.559    & 20,5\%    & 42.773    &      
 18,7\%\\      
 \hline
Asiste  & 164.034   & 80,7\%    & 192.553   & 79,5\%    & 182.206        
 & 81,3\%\\ \hline
Total   & 242.112   & 100\% & 242.112   & 100\% & 224.979   & 100\%\\ 
 \hline
 \end{tabular}\\
 \\
 \raggedrigth{Fuente: ECH2011, elaboración propia}
 \end{table}


 \begin{figure}[H]
 \caption{Asistencia a la educación de jóvenes de 14 a 17 años por año.}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{img1}\\
  \raggedrigth{Fuente: ECH2011, elaboración propia}
 \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You have a typo: replace `\raggedrigth` with `raggedright` (several times).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing setting `singlelinecheck=false`.

Here's a complete example (where I've removed the irrelevant packages and added `booktabs`)

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, spanish]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption} 

\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=RaggedRight,labelfont=bf,textfont=bf,skip=10pt}
\captionsetup[figure]{justification=RaggedRight,labelfont=bf,textfont=bf,skip=10pt}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htp]
\RaggedRight

\caption{Asistencia a la educación de jóvenes de 14 a 17 según edades simples.}

\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{2009} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2010} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2011}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
Asistencia
 & Frecuencia & Porcentaje & Frecuencia & Porcentaje & Frecuencia & Porcentaje\\ 
\midrule
No Asiste & 39.169 & 19,3\%    & 49.559    & 20,5\%    & 42.773    &   18,7\%\\      
Asiste  & 164.034   & 80,7\%    & 192.553   & 79,5\%    & 182.206  & 81,3\%\\
Total   & 242.112   & 100\% & 242.112   & 100\% & 224.979   & 100\%\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\medskip

Fuente: ECH2011, elaboración propia
\end{table}


\begin{figure}[htp]
\RaggedRight

\caption{Asistencia a la educación de jóvenes de 14 a 17 años por año.}

\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{img1}

\medskip

Fuente: ECH2011, elaboración propia

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Some notes.

1. `\raggedright` is a declaration, not a command with argument; since you want all tables and figures ragged right, just issue `\RaggedRight` at the start.
2. Don't use `[H]`; it seems good at the beginning, but it raises more problems than it solves. Let floats float. `;-)`
3. I've changed the appearance of the table using commands provided by `booktabs`. If you want to use ruled tables, correct some points; it should be `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{...}` (the rule belongs to the cell before it, only the leftmost rule belongs to the cell after it); also `\cline{2-2}\cline{3-3}...` should be more simply `\cline{2-7}`.